# Why does my SQL scalar function sometimes throws "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted..."

Tags: sql, exception, sql-server-2019

I am directly calling user defined function in my database. Problem is the function seems to randomly return correct value or throw an error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` even without changes in the database and it's few seconds apart of previous call.

Calling syntax of function:

`select dbo.uf_construction_price(16)`

Body of function:

```sql
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_construction_price]
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS numeric(19,6)
AS
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE @rounding INT
    SELECT @rounding = rounding from construction_settings WHERE construction_id = @id

    DECLARE @price NUMERIC(19,6)

    SET @price = (SELECT ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(ROUND(ROUND(ISNULL(bi.joc,0),2) * ROUND(ISNULL(bi.value,0),isnull(@rounding,3)),2)),2),0) 
    FROM budget_items bi 
    WHERE is_available != 1 AND construction_id = @id)

    RETURN isnull(@price,0.00)
END
```

I've tried numerous thing debugging this problem and these are more descriptive behavior based on my research:

- When calling the body as is, it's not throwing the error.
- The error is thrown on the row with `SET @price =` where the subsequent query **sometimes returns multiple results** even when it should't be possible with `SUM` (when using TOP 1, it seems like it returns un-summed results)
- Compatibility results seems to be corelated with the problem (different behavior), but again, no hard evidence on that.
- When I replace row `SET @price =` with this code snippet, it seems to be working correctly, but again, I don't know why:

```sql
    declare @Temp TABLE (id int)
    insert into @Temp
    SELECT ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(ROUND(ROUND(ISNULL(bi.joc,0),2) * ROUND(ISNULL(bi.value,0),isnull(@rounding,3)),2)),2),0) 
    FROM budget_items bi 
    WHERE is_available != 1 AND construction_id = @id

    SET @price = (SELECT * FROM @Temp)
```

Comment: @jarlh - A scalar aggregate (which this is due to presence of `SUM` and no `GROUP BY`) always returns exactly one row

Comment: Can you give us a [mre]? What version of SQL Server are you on? What does `@@version` return?

Comment: Could be an issue with the first query `SELECT @rounding = rounding` returning more than one row which would just give an undeterministic result generally but may cause problems when scalar function inlining is applied,

Comment: @MartinSmith I know it should, but as I said, the TOP 1 sometimes returns a different result, it's really strange

Comment: @ThomA How is it possible to create minimal reproducible example for SQL query?

The @@version returns this:
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB5029377) - 15.0.2104.1 (X64)   Aug 16 2023 00:09:21   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 22621: )

Comment: @MartinSmith I am 100% certain the problem is on the `SET @price =` row, because when using TOP 1, the query never fails but sometimes, returns different result

Comment: I would expect to do with scalar UDF inlining. Your workaround with the table variable will stop it being inlined

Comment: This may well be an issue that is fixed; that you've not installed any CUs means you won't have those fixes.

Comment: An [mre] would reproduce the issue, with DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Perhaps, however, the real solution is to switch to a iTVF.

Comment: Almost certainly a bug with inlining of `SELECT @rounding = rounding from...`. You need a `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` to get a deterministic result. Inlining was disabled in later builds for this type of query without a `TOP` and `ORDER BY`, due to this bug. You should upgrade to the latest build anyway, even if you fix the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is probably not on the line with the `SUM`, as that is already aggregating, and is guaranteed to return a single value. It's almost certainly on the earlier query

```sql
SELECT @rounding = rounding from construction_settings WHERE construction_id = @id
```

This has no `TOP (1)` and no `ORDER BY`, so multiple results could be returned.

If the function was not inlined then the extra results would be ignored. And with the latest builds of SQL Server, even an inlined function would use an internal `ANY()` aggregate to ensure a single result.

But your RTM build appears to have a bug, in that it will inline it into something like

```sql
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT rounding = (SELECT rounding from construction_settings WHERE construction_id = @id)
)
```

Firstly, fix the issue itself by adding a `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) @rounding = rounding
FROM construction_settings
WHERE construction_id = @id
ORDER BY someValueHere;
```

**Make sure to upgrade** to the [latest build of SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2019/build-versions). This would have prevented the issue in the first place.

---

**Much better,** is to turn your scalar UDF into a Table Valued Function instead, which you can inline yourself.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.uf_construction_price
(
    @id int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  price =
    ISNULL(
      ROUND(
        SUM(
          ROUND(
            ROUND(ISNULL(bi.joc, 0), 2)
            * ROUND(ISNULL(bi.value, 0), isnull(cs.rounding, 3)),
            2
          )
        ),
        2
      ),
      0
    ) 
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) cs.rounding
    FROM construction_settings cs
    WHERE cs.construction_id = @id
    ORDER BY someValueHere
) cs
FROM budget_items bi 
WHERE bi.is_available != 1
  AND bi.construction_id = @id
;
```

I must say, your rounding logic is rather strange, but whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to helpful folks in comments for clarifying that I did not have installed any Cumulative Updates for SQL Server 2019 including **CU 2 with fixes for Scalar UDF Inlining**, which was the culprit in my trouble

Sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/releases/sqlserver-2019/cumulativeupdate2
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2022-and-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d

Comment: It's [more](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2022-and-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) than just CU2 that added fixes (read additional limitations) to inlining.